# How to get the size of some rows in a table

Tags: sql-server

First of all sorry for my english, I know it is not perfect

I have the table in my DB in whtch I have about 40 columns, and I need to get size of some records in this table to make a report.

I tried to do something with dbcc SHOWCONTIG, but I didn't get satisfactory results.

Have you any advice/ideas to solve my problem?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you mean storage requirements? If so this may help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: I need to find out `what is the number of bytes a set of records from this table occupies on disk` as @i-one say :)

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Here's a link for 2012 that may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175991.aspx

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest writing a query to calculate based on contents using the reference info here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-data-types-reference/

E.g. let's say your table has 2 columns: A `varchar(20)`, and a `datetime`. Then your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT RowID, -- Some identifier for the row, e.g. primary key
       LEN(varcharcolumn) + 2 -- Length of varchar is L + 2 bytes
       + 8 -- Length of datetime column is 8 bytes
       ) AS TotalBytes
-- Add WHERE clause to restrict rows in report
```

Comment: downvoted because the poster is asking for a SQL Server solution; not MySQL.  There's a possibility that the query could be modified to work, but you should give some guidance on how to do that.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth Good spot, not sure why I thought it was MySQL. Method would be similar for SQL - have changed the answer to reflect this.

Comment: But i have about 40 columns and i would like to make this query universal if it's possible

Comment: @zakir Agree there's a bit of effort involved here with 40 columns but it should be possible using this method - I've used a similar method with tables in an Oracle database on a previous project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want data type lengths try selecting from INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get the structure of a table.

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

should suffice. The column CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH gives you string lengths.

Comment: I need physical size of existing records, so I do not know if it is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I exactly understand your need, but may be `DataLength` function will help you:

```
select DataLength(ColumnOfInterest)
from TableName
where <filter condition>
```

for a set of columns:

```
select DataLength(ColumnOfInterest1) + DataLength(ColumnOfInterest2) + etc.
from TableName
where <filter condition>
```

Comment: But in this solution, i think, i need to get DataLength of every column

Comment: @zakir, to get data length for a set of columns it should be `select DataLength(Column1) + DataLength(Column2) + etc.`. However, if you need answer to question _what is the number of bytes a set of records from this table occupies on disk_, then this one is not answering it.

Comment: As you say, i need to know `what is the number of bytes a set of records from this table occupies on disk` :)

Comment: @zakir, unfortunately I have no solution for this

Answer (score 0):

In sql server it is easy to get the size of a table. So another approach is to store the  records you would like filtered in a separate table, and then just get the size of the table.

Below is an example:

```
--CREATE A TABLE TO STORE YOUR FILTERED RECORDS
CREATE TABLE dbo.resulttable
(
    id INT,
    employee VARCHAR(32)
)
GO

--INSERT FILTERED RECORDS IN NEW TABLE
INSERT INTO dbo.resulttable (id,employee)
SELECT id,employee FROM dbo.originaltable WHERE id > 100

GO
--GET SIZE OF TABLE WHICH HAS THE FILTERED RECORDS WITH HOWEVER MANY COLUMNS
SELECT 
    t.name AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME = 'resulttable' 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name

GO
```